# Where should I report sites that have obvious signs of black hat abuse?

Tags: google, blackhat

I have found several sites that are using black hat techniques to rank higher in search results. Where can I report those sites.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The quality guidelines section of the [Google Webmaster Guidelines](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=35769) contains [this link](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/spamreport?hl=en) for submitting sites which use blackhat/spammy practices. I believe the feedback page on Google search results also has a link to the same form.

**Edit:**

Google [has also released](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2010/11/chrome-extension-for-reporting-webspam.html) a [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/efinmbicabejjhjafeidhfbojhnfiepj) to easily report spam sites. It provides a browser button that'll take you directly to the spam site submission form and autocomplete certain fields.

There is also a [similar plugin for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/spamreport/).